# Find Anagrams in the Dictionary

Tags: string, fastest-algorithm, permutations

This a code challenge. **The winner will be the person to provide the most efficient implementation of the solution in terms of algorithmic complexity.**

Using the dictionary found in '/usr/share/dict' (on OS X and Linux), your task is to find the word with the most anagrams of itself in the dictionary, and print all of the words that are the anagrams.

Comment: Unless you're certain that the problem is sufficiently difficult, "first person to solve the question" is usually a bad winning criteria because it would disadvantage anyone who's asleep right now.

Comment: Also, what happens if the efficiency is in terms of the length of the words? Because surely you need to traverse the words themselves in order to decide if any two are anagrams of each other...

Comment: You are both right, I will rephrase the question to make it more generic. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I think "most efficient" is underspecified. Can one preprocess the dictionary? Does one find anagrams of a single word or a list of words? Is this about actual performance on real dictionaries, or worst-case theoretical behavior?

Comment: Ok. Should I change it to most creative?

Comment: You need to add an objective measure for answers. I suggest algorithmic complexity (O(logn) > O(n) > O(nlogn) > O(n^2) etc). In the event of a tie, you should pick another measure (eg: fastest single threaded execution, least run-time space, most votes, oldest answer ;-).

Comment: Also, if you mean to assess answers on performance of the /usr/share/dict file, say so. Not 'Assume you have' but 'You will use'.

Comment: You added the [fastest-code] tag (which is for fastest runtime speed), but you mention algorithmic complexity in your challenge. Which one is the actual criterion? (in case of algorithmic complexity, use the [fastest-algorithm] tag)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2

Efficient to write, and reasonably efficient to run.

```
groups = {}
for word in open('/usr/share/dict/words'):
    word = word.strip()
    signature = ''.join(sorted(list(word)))
    if signature not in groups:
        groups[signature]=[]
    groups[signature].append(word)
anagrams = groups.values()
maxlen = max(len(x) for x in anagrams)
for group in (x for x in anagrams if len(x) == maxlen):
    print ' '.join(sorted(group))
```

produces:

```
carets caster caters crates reacts recast traces
pares parse pears rapes reaps spare spear
```

in about 0.4 seconds.

The algorithm has O(n) complexity. The full word list is processed in 0.42 seconds. A half-size word list is processed in the expected 0.21 seconds.

Comment: Sorting each word alphabetically is considered the "correct" solution. +1.

Comment: Edited to add sort on output.

Answer (score 2):

## C++ 14 - 0.077 seconds for 52875 words

---

Code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


void thread_func(mutex& file_lock, mutex& map_lock, map<string, vector<string>>& anagrams, ifstream& file) {
    string word;
    string sorted_word;
    while (true) {
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> locker(file_lock);
            if (file.eof()) {
                return;
            }
            file >> word;
        }
        sorted_word = word;
        sort(sorted_word.begin(), sorted_word.end());
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> locker(map_lock);
            anagrams[sorted_word].push_back(word);
        }
    }
}

void nothread_func(map<string, vector<string>>& anagrams, ifstream& file) {
    string word;
    string sorted_word;
    while (true) {
        if (file.eof()) {
            return;
        }
        file >> word;
        sorted_word = word;
        sort(sorted_word.begin(), sorted_word.end());
        anagrams[sorted_word].push_back(word);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string fname = "/usr/share/dict/words";
    int number_of_threads = 1;

    if (argc > 1) {
        fname = argv[1];
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        number_of_threads = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    mutex file_lock;
    mutex map_lock;
    map<string, vector<string>> anagrams;
    cout << "Opening file '" << fname << "'" << endl;
    ifstream file(fname);
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "Could not open file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (number_of_threads == 1) {
        nothread_func(anagrams, file);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Starting " << number_of_threads << " threads" << endl;

        vector<thread> threads;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i) {
            thread th(thread_func, ref(file_lock), ref(map_lock), ref(anagrams), ref(file));
            threads.push_back(move(th));
        }
        for (auto& thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
        cout << "Threads done" << endl;
    }
    int largest_size = max_element(anagrams.begin(), anagrams.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b){return a.second.size() < b.second.size();})->second.size();
    for (auto p : anagrams) {
        if (p.second.size() == largest_size) {
            for (auto word : p.second) {
                cout << word << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Compile: `g++ anagrams.cpp -o anagrams --std=c++14 -pthread -ggdb -O3`

CLI: `./anagrams <wordfile, defaults to /usr/share/dict/words> <number of threads, defaults to 1>`

Example:

```
$ wc -l /usr/share/dict/cracklib-small
52875 /usr/share/dict/cracklib-small
$ time ./anagrams /usr/share/dict/cracklib-small
Opening file '/usr/share/dict/cracklib-small'
caret carte cater crate react recta trace 
pares parse pears rapes reaps spare spear 

real    0m0.077s
user    0m0.073s
sys     0m0.000s
```

The code does have multithreaded built in, but it slows things down on my system. Might be useful on slower systems / bigger files. If the number of threads is `1`, it disables threads and does everything normally. Algorithm is essentially the same as CarpetPython's, but my code is slightly longer (well, 81 lines).